# Teradata module for python: could not find a version that satisfies the requirement teradata

Tags: python, teradata

When trying to install the Teradata Python-module, I receive following error.

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement teradata (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution for teradata

I'm running `python 3.6.4` through the latest Anaconda distribution on `Windows 7.0`.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks

**EDIT:** It seems this was a rookie problem. My company's firewall seems to block pip installs. Simply connecting to another network resolved this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this was a rookie problem. My company's firewall seems to block pip installs. Simply connecting to another network resolved this.